# Wordpress site changed to HTTPS from HTTP after reinstall. And does not see some of the pictures

Tags: php, wordpress, xampp, elementor

I changed some files in config sites and my site broke. So I reinstalled wordpress and replace in the new install wp-admin, wp-content, wp-includes with old folders. Used the same database. Now my site is only working on https not on http like it was before and it fails to load certain images and thumbnail. When i am inspecting the page the images have the 404 error and they work when replacing their url from http to https. Is there a general fix for that? What should i do.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpmFy.png)

Comment: you'd probably want to use https as that is the standard for the web now. looks like this (https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-ssl-and-https-in-wordpress/) might be able to help? Specifcally the better search plugin

Answer (score 0):

you might want to re-sync all the files on your website with this plugin. https://wordpress.org/plugins/media-sync/, some of the file url might be still on the "http" that's why when you access the website with https it wont load.

Comment: I managed to load images by changing in General Settings the urls from http to https. And everything is working fine for now. I am wandering how i can go back to  http becuse in the https i have the Not Secure Warning.